# "source not found" when trying to open string source code

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying to ctrl-click on String (in eclipse) and It said: "source not found".
I searched for the answer online and couldn't find one.
can you help me fix that?

Comment: Usually there's a button such as "lookup source" or something that lets you pick the sdk's sources.

Comment: and what do i choose?

Comment: You must be using a JDK to be able to see the source of String, if you just have a JRE the source is not included. What do you have in 'Java > Installed JREs' in the Preferences?

Comment: And which of those possibly multiple entries is your project set to use?

Comment: in 'Java > Installed JREs' in the Preferences, I have JRE, but I have JDK installed on my pc.